# Fastest converging series of resistors

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am looking for a recursive circuit which grows very fast and has a finite resistance but an infinite number of resistors.
I have found many ways to get a finite given resistance with an infinite number of resistors. Many ways are recursive including these:
In this one each resistor is equal but can be replaced with the entire set of circuits and the resistance stays the same.
$R_{total}={1\over{{1\over r}+{1\over r}}}+{1\over{{1\over r}+{1\over r}}}$
[image: recursive circuit 1]
Here each resistor is also equal and this pattern goes on indefinitely but the circuit approaches ${\sqrt{5}+1}\over{2}$ times the resistance of each resistor.
$R_{total}={{\sqrt{5}+1}\over2}*r={1\over{1+R_{total}}}$
[image]
In the first one after n iterations the number of resistors is $4^n$.
In the second one after n iterations the number of resistors is $2n$.
So we get more resistors faster with the first circuit.
My question is what is the fastest growing recursive circuit possible.

Comment: I'm guessing you want a nonzero final resistance?

Comment: A silly way would be to take a resistor, and replace it with an infinite number of resistors in parallel along with one in series.  The total resistance wouldn't change, but after one iteration, you'd have an infinite number of resistors.  That's pretty fast, I guess.  Is there some restriction on the problem that prevents this from being a valid solution?

Comment: @Brionius That makes sense and I didn't really state anything that would prevent that from being a solution. The concept I am trying to explore is how fast given series diverge so It doesn't help much for that but it is technically correct.